# Exception importing Drools/Guvnor repository exported file

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, drools, drools-guvnor

Im trying to import rules and assets into a new drool/guvnor installation, but I am getting the following error:
[image: erros/exceptions when importing]

I'm using a RedHat JBoss version 5.3.1.BRMS and I'm importing this way: Administration-> Import/Export --> choose file 'repository_export.zip' or repository_export.xml).

This error is occurring in a Windos 7 Ultimate 64bits+Java 1.7.0_09u.

I've tried using the same BRMS and exported the same zip file in other machine (Win7Business 64bits+Java 1.6.0_35) and it imported just fine.

Does anyone knows how can I resolve it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just uninstalled one of the two jdk in the PC (jdk 1.6, in this case) and it's working fine now.